# Selecting 1 ball of each type from the box

Tags: probability

There are n White balls and n Black balls in a box. You repeatedly withdraw 2 balls simultaneously till the box is empty. Find the probability such that every withdrawal consists of 1 White ball and 1 Black ball?

EDIT:-let's just find the probability for the first simultaneous withdrawal of 2 balls such that 1 is W and 1 is B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try a long winded way of doing this through classical probability. I think the below is correct.

Let number of remaining white balls be $w_i$ and similarly for black balls $b_i$ where $i$ is the ordinal number denoting the draw, e.g. $i=1$ for the first draw. Initially, there are a total of $2n$ balls in the box and that $i=0$, the number of white balls is $w_0=n$ and number of black balls is $b_0=n$.

At the first draw, i.e. $i=1$, the probability for drawing one white and one black ball is given by the probability of drawing a white first then black, denoted $P(b_1|w_1)$ plus that of drawing a black first then black, denoted $P(w_1|b_1)$. They are given by:

$P(b_1|w_1)=\frac{b_1}{(b_1+w_1)}\times\frac{w_1}{(b_1+w_1-1)}$

$P(w_1|b_1)=\frac{w_1}{(b_1+w_1)}\times\frac{b_1}{(b_1+w_1-1)}$

Notice that they are equal to each other. Hence,

$P(b_1,w_1)=P(b_1|w_1)+P(w_1|b_1)=\frac{2w_1b_1}{(b_1+w_1)(b_1+w_1-1)}=\frac{2n^2}{2n(2n-1)}=\frac{n}{(2n-1)}$

Now we have to generalize for second draw, third draw and so on. To do so, note that since there were $n$ white balls initially, the number of white balls $w_i$ after the $i^\text{th}$ draw is given by $w_i=n-i+1$. For example, if we had 10 white balls, at the second draw we would have $10-2+1=9$ white balls left. We can apply the same logic for the black balls and obtain the identical formula $b_i = n-i+1$. One then obtains the probability of drawing 1 white and 1 black ball at the $i^\text{th}$ draw (provided one have done so similarly up to this point in previous draws) as:

$P(b_i,w_i)=\frac{2w_ib_i}{(b_i+w_i)(b_i+w_i-1)}=\frac{2(n-i+1)^2}{(2(n-i+1))(2(n-i+1)-1)}=\frac{(n-i+1)}{2(n-i+1)-1}$

The probability $P(d)$ for a chain of consecutive draws of one black and one white happening, until box is empty (this is when $n$ draws have happened s.t. $i=n$) is simply the cumulative product of $P(b_i,w_i)$. We obtain:

$\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}{\frac{(n-i+1)}{2(n-i+1)-1}}=\frac{(2^{-n}(-n)_n)}{(0.5-n)_n}$

where $(x)_n$ is the falling factorial such that $(x)_n=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)$. A table of values for a box with $2n$ balls, i.e. $n$ white and $n$ black balls and the probability of drawing one of each consecutively 2 at a time, until the box is empty, is given by:

<kbd>$n$</kbd><kbd>$P(d)\!\:$</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>$\;\;\; 1\;\;\;$</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>$\;\:\!\;\frac{2}{3}\;\:\;$</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>$\;\:\!\;\frac{2}{5}\;\:\;$</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>$\;\!\;\frac{8}{35}\;\:\;$</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>$\;\!\;\frac{8}{63}\;\:\;$</kbd>
<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>$\;\frac{16}{231}\;\!\;$</kbd>

Comment: "the probability for drawing one white and one black ball is given by the probability of drawing a white first then black, denoted P(b1|w1) plus that of drawing a black first then black, denoted P(w1|b1). " The problem here is that the balls are being drawn simultaneously not one after the other. so i think you are wrong. I would love u to prove me wrong or if someone else agrees with your answer .

Comment: @Atul Ganwar  It is a semantic distinction, it makes no difference mathematically. Drawing two balls you have only 4 distinct possibilities: 1 W and 1B, 1B and 1W, or 2W or 2Bs, The calculation here take care of the possibilities of both the  1 W and 1B & 1B and 1W cases.

Comment: well i would get back to you after some more research. Watch the space!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** removed the first hint, which is treated in other answers

---

Another approach: <s>You are taking the $2n$ balls in some order. To get the probability that the $(2k-1)$th ball and the $2k$th ball have different colours for all $k=1,2,\dots,n$, you may calculate the number of arrangements such that this condition is true and the number of all possible arrangements.</s>

Whether you draw two balls simultaneously or one at a time does not really matter, as long as you are checking them two at a time. Thus, you are drawing the $2n$ balls in an order. Every possible arrangement of $n$ black and $n$ white balls has an equal probability. The probability of getting a favorable outcome is the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of possible outcomes.

Let $(a_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,2n$ be the sequence of outcomes ($W$ or $B$) of the draws. A sequence is favorable if and only if $a_{2k-1}\neq a_{2k}$ for each $k=1,\dots,n$ (the number of $W$s and $B$s are equal in that case). For each $k$, there are two different ways to order $W$ and $B$ such that this condition applies. Therefore, the number of favorable outcomes is $n$. On the other hand, the number of possible outcomes is ${2n \choose n}$, so the answer to your question is
$$2^n \Big/ {2n \choose n}$$.

Comment: well i loved your second approach. According to it total different arrangements of the 2n balls with n W & n B = [(2n)!/n!n!].
Total favourable cases = 2 i.e WBWBWBWB.... and BWBWBWBW...

SO, PROB = 2/[(2n)!/n!n!]  . what say?

Comment: Favorable cases include WB|BW|BW|BW|WB... and similar, so the total number is 2^n (n pairs for which two different orders are valid).

Comment: Actually, because the first approach is considered in other answers, I'll remove it from my answer to keep things simple and elaborate on the other idea.

Comment: yes.missed it :(

Answer (score 0):

According to me the probability for withdrawing 1W & 1B simultaneously(one time) out of n W & n B balls , would be the probability of case BW out of cases WW,BB,BW(same as WB). That is 1/3 . But the problem is that all the cases aren't equally likely .

**THIS ANSWER SEEMS RIGHT TO ME**

total different arrangements of the 2n balls with n W & n B = [(2n)!/n!n!]. Total favourable cases = 2 i.e WBWBWBWB.... and BWBWBWBW... SO, PROB = 2/[(2n)!/n!n!] .

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ of each, then there are $n^2$ pairs such that one is white and the other is black.  There are $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2!}$ pairs such that both are white, and there are $\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2!}$ pairs such that both are black.

Example to illustrate why we divide by 2!: If the balls in the bin are W1,W2,W3,B1,B2,B3, then the pairs of W/W are: (W1,W2),(W1,W3),(W2,W1),(W2,W3),(W3,W1),(W3,W2). Notice though, that there are duplicates (W1,W2) represents the same pair as (W2,W1).  So that is why we divide by 2!. When calculating B/W pairs, we aren't going to double count since B always first, W is always second.

So the probability of your pair being a white and black is $\frac{n^2}{(2n^2-2n)/2!+n^2}=\frac{n}{2n-1}$

So to answer your original question, the probability of ALL removals being W/B would be $\frac{n}{2n-1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2n-3}\cdot\frac{n-2}{2n-5}...\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot 1$

It's also interesting to note that it didn't matter that you drew the balls simultaneously since if you draw one ball, then whether it's white or black, there are n balls remaining of $2n-1$ that are desirable to be drawn next.

Comment: according to this approach the answer for n withdrawal would become 
[your answer]^(n-1) . 
{(n-1) because for the last case(W,B) the probability would be 1}
Which is essentially different from your first answer????/

Comment: Yes, I fixed the arithmetic.

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: I also added n! when considering the pairs of white/white and black/black.  Now it should be correct.

Comment: NO!!!!! that would mean no. of pairs <1 . I know u want to consider the fact that n balls are same but this is not the situation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... the formula works for 1W/1B (probability 1), and 2W/2B (probability 2/3)

Comment: u divide by (x)![where x is the no. of objects of same type] only when the permutation is of n objects! [n>=x1 +x2 +..]

Comment: ". There are n⋅(n−1)/n! pairs "  for n=4 there would be .5 pairs . haha :P

Comment: You are right -- I meant 2!, not n!.

Comment: why do you divide by 2!? Even if you do, shouldn't you divide n^2 by 2 too?

Comment: When forming a pair out of whites, I choose a white one, then another white one.  If I do not divide by 2! I am double counting. (Imagine the balls are labeled w1/w2... drawing w1, then w2 is the same as w2 then w1.

But when I am counting pairs of white/black -- I choose a white then a black.  There is no way to double count here since my first choice is white, second is black.

Comment: "When calculating B/W pairs, we aren't going to double count since B always first, W is always second." That means you missed the cases for W first and B second . Therefore you need to multiply by 2 here!

Comment: No, we're just counting pairs -- not counting the ways that we draw the balls.

Comment: you are right. My bad. Still let me search further. Watch the space

Answer (score 0):

With four possible outcomes on the first draw and two of which are 1W 1B your initial draw chance would be 50%.  For any successive draws to also be 1W 1B its as simple as .5n

```
.5n
```

Comment: nope. out of the four outcomes WB & BW are same(no order as simultaneous pick). therefore total cases= 3. Moreover, the three cases aren't equally likely to occur. And even if they were(which they should not be) the answer would be {1/3}^(n-1) .  {(n-1) because for the last case the probability would be 1}